# Making Sense of AdMob Mediation Fill Rate

Tags: admob

My question is regarding the Fill Rates displayed under AdMob's Mediation Report.

I'm trying to get an accurate percentage of unfilled request, however with AdMob's reporting this does not seem to be as straight forward as it should be. This is easy when using just AdMob alone, but gets more tricky when mediating other networks.

The Total Fill rate of AdMob + Other Mediated Networks displayed under Mediation Report, seems to be based on Impressions / Total Requests, **and not Impressions / Unique Requests**.

However, Total Requests includes duplicate requests across the mediation stack resulting in a single ad impression. So, for example a single ad request from a single page view may result in 5 requests if mediating 5 different networks.

In understanding a total percentage of actual page views across all networks that resulted in filled requests should I manually just divide Impressions / Unique Requests, or am I missing something here?

I really don't understand why AdMob doesn't compute this Unique Request Fill rate automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Ed Weng and I'm currently the Product Manager responsible for AdMob reporting. You're not missing anything and you're totally right... The overall fill rate should be  **Impressions / Unique Requests**. This is something we are currently in the process of fixing and you should see a corrected number in the near future! Stay tuned!

Best,
Ed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Glad someone is looking at this. Hope this gets fixed soon as I'm sure many other have asked that same question.

Comment: Status on this? Deployed yet? I can see "unique requests" as a separate value in the "Ad mediation report". 
Also, I want to calculate total match rate (matched/requests) for the full mediation stack. Is that data easily available?

Comment: Has this been fixed yet? Please let us know. Thanks.

Comment: This has not been fixed yet. In the meantime, please continue calculating the fill rate as Impressions / Unique Requests. Stay tuned!